# Where is the bash command redirecting to

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I am trying to use the following bash command "command < f1 > f2 2> f3" will it work as follows?

- stdin from f1 will be redirected to the command
- stdout from the command will be redirected to f2
- and stderr from the command will be redirected to f3

Thanks

Comment: I think it depends on what command you use, e.g I tried this with cat command, and cat command uses the same work flow you mentioned. What other commands you could be using?

Comment: Yes. I would amend the first sentence as follows. f1 will be redirected to the command as stdin.

Comment: Answer: basically, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When executing the command line

```
somecommand <f1 >f2 2>f3
```

1. the shell will connect `f1` with the command's standard input stream, and
2. the command's standard output stream with `f2`, and
3. the command's standard error stream to `f3`,

in this order.

Note that the order of the redirections matter:

- If `f1` is not readable, then an error will be produced (by the shell), and the command will not execute. Neither `f2` nor `f3` will be created or truncated.
- If `f2` is not writable, then an error will be produced (by the shell), and the command will not execute. `f3` will not be created or truncated.
- If `f3` is not writable, then an error will be produced (by the shell), and the command will not execute. `f2` will still be created and/or truncated.

The relative location of `somecommand` on the command line, however, does not matter.

```
somecommand <f1 >f2 2>f3
```

is the same as

```
<f1 somecommand >f2 2>f3
```

and as

```
<f1 >f2 somecommand 2>f3
```

and as

```
<f1 >f2 2>f3 somecommand
```

This is because the redirections are handled separately from the command that they affect, and they are not command line arguments of the command.

See also:

- [How is this command legal ? “> file1 < file2 cat”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356118/how-is-this-command-legal-file1-file2-cat)